# Android: SQLite database not in internal memory

Tags: android, database, sqlite, memory

I'm writing an Android application that creates and populates a SQLite Database at runtime. In similar apps, the database gets automatically created in the "/data/data//databases/" directory. However, that isn't happening this time. I've gotten into "/data/data/" via adb shell, but there is no /databases/ directory, let alone a database in there. However, I know my database is getting created and populated because I print out the first ten entries to check. Where else could it be stored? I have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, and my code gives no errors.

If it helps, here is my database helper class (relevant parts):

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int VERSION = 1;

    private static int colNum;
    private static String dbName, tableName, filePath;
    private static String[] cols;
    private final Context myContext;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, dbName, null, VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }


    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            File dbFile = new File(filePath);
            fr = new FileReader(dbFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader buffer;
        buffer = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = "";
        String firstLine;

        try {
            firstLine = buffer.readLine();
            cols = firstLine.split(",");    // get name of columns from header (first row of .csv)
            colNum = cols.length;           // number of columns in each row of the file
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String table_col = getTableCols(colNum, cols);

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName + ";");
        String create = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + table_col;
        db.execSQL(create);

        populateDB(db, buffer, line);
    }

    public void populateDB(SQLiteDatabase db, BufferedReader buffer, String line) {

        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] row = line.split(",");
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                for (int i = 0; i < colNum; i++) {
                    cv.put(cols[i], row[i].trim());
                }
                db.insert(tableName, null, cv);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
    }

    public String getTableCols(Integer num, String[] cols) {
        String table_col = "(";
        for (int i = 0; i < (num - 1); i++) {
            table_col += (cols[i] + " text, ");
        }
        table_col += cols[num - 1] + " text)";
        return table_col;
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName + ";");
        //Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The database is created in `databases` under your application-specific data directory. On many but not all firmwares the data directory is `/data/data/your.package.name` so the databases location would be `/data/data/your.package.name/databases/`.

The application data directory is protected with filesystem permissions. You cannot access it unless you have root or you're running with your package's uid.

Comment: But that's what is so weird - the directory /data/data/my.package.name/databases/ doesn't exist at all. I have been accessing it by running with my packages uid, and there's nothing there.

Comment: How are you invoking the db helper? You need one of the `get...Database()` methods to actually create the db. Also, a transaction in the population code is probably not a good idea. sqlite helper lifecycle callbacks are already wrapped in tranactions, sqlite doesn't support nested transaction itself and Android's attempt to work around the limitations is flaky at best.